# Incorrect date value when trying to save date to Mysql from nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql

In my React project, I am using material-ui TimePicker with momentUtils. Upon selecting a date I am getting the value as a moment object that has the following elements:

_d:
_isAMomentObject:
_isUTC:
_isValid:
_locale:

I noticed my date value is coming at the '_d' element in this format:

> Tue May 05 2020 11:08:00 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)

Now I have been trying to save this value on my mysql db, where my field date is of date type and I just keep getting mysql error: "Incorrect date value". So what are considered valid dates on mysql and how can I parse the value I am getting as a valid date before sending it to db?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using momentObj.toISOString() before saving it. Usually it wants it in iso format.

Comment: It parsed the object into the expected format however still getting this error:
code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE',
  errno: 1292,
  sqlMessage: "Incorrect date value: '2020-05-04T04:47:00.000Z' for column 'user_date' at row 1",
  sqlState: '22007',